# Will Huntresses still add buffs to other huntress when you kill an enemy with Phantasmal Claw?

Tags: soda-dungeon-2

I want to get a ton of Huntress bonus damage stacked up, so I'm investigating the item *Phantasmal Claw*. I'm not sure if it still gives Huntress stacks when the claw kills an enemy.

Does Phantasmal Claw stack with the Huntress buffs? Or is it just a worse Darkmage ability that you can put on any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, after some testing, I've concluded that *Phantasmal Claw* stacks with the Huntress' buffs, *and* buffs the Huntress.